# Is there a way to accomplish `renderToStaticMarkup` on the client-side in React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-18, react-dom-server

We are currently using `ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup` to render a tooltip within `highcharts`.

```
 const chartOptions: Options = {
    chart: { height },
    tooltip: {
      ...,
      formatter: function () {
        return ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
          <OurComponent/>
        )
      }
    },
```

However in React 18, the `renderToStaticMarkup` API was removed when React is running in the browser and there is no way that I'm aware of on the client-side to retrieve the static HTML that would be generated from the React component.

We do not have a node server so cannot migrate to `SSR` to accomplish this.

Highcharts is framework-agnostic so they only accept raw HTML.

Is anyone aware of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

`renderToStaticMarkup` is NOT removed from `react-dom/server`.  It turned out that we had an incorrect alias in our local `webpack.config.js`